# Titanium Admob keeps on checking for new ads

Tags: android, titanium, admob

I am using titanium admob module, [found here](http://gitt.io/component/ti.admob)

My app has several pages, so i load ads on several of them.

My problem is that after a few visits, each of the ads doesn't seem to get garbage collected or killed, so in my output I can see a lot of info statements indicating the app is checking for ads. These are **not** happening every 60 seconds, much closer to every 5 seconds.

I'm assuming this is going to cause some degredation/battery use while the app runs.

Does anybody know how I'm meant to "kill" the refresh of an admob ad? If it is specific to titanium, great. If it is specific to android, well, let me know the method calls and the concept and I'll see if i can translate that across to the js titanium code!

```
[INFO] :   Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
[INFO] :   Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
[INFO] :   Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
[INFO] :   Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
[INFO] :   Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
[INFO] :   Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Analytics Service Started
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Stopping Analytics Service
[INFO] :   Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
[INFO] :   Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
[INFO] :   Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
[INFO] :   Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
[INFO] :   Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
[INFO] :   Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
[INFO] :   Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
[INFO] :   Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
[INFO] :   Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
[INFO] :   Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

Answer (score 0):

onPause() method of the Activity Life cycle, consider to pause the AdView mGoogleAdView;

```
           if (mGoogleAdView != null) {
                mGoogleAdView.pause();
            }
```

In onDestroy method of Life cycle consider to

```
 mGoogleAdView.destroy();
```

P.S: I have not used Titanium.